# chrome.scripting.executeScript: "function is not defined" error

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I am writing a Chrome Extension and I have this page:

```
<html>
  <body>
    <button id="changeColor"></button>
    <script src="popup.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

With this JS (popup.js):

```
let changeColor = document.getElementById("changeColor");

chrome.storage.sync.get("color", ({ color }) => {
  changeColor.style.backgroundColor = color;
});

changeColor.addEventListener("click", async () => {
    let [tab] = await chrome.tabs.query({ active: true, currentWindow: true });
  
    chrome.scripting.executeScript({
      target: { tabId: tab.id },
      function: setPageBackgroundColor,
    });

});
  
function setPageBackgroundColor() {
  chrome.storage.sync.get("color", ({ color }) => {
    document.body.style.backgroundColor = color;
  });
  // Here, it says: Uncaught ReferenceError: getElementByXpath is not defined
  console.log(getElementByXpath("xpath").textContent);
}
  
function getElementByXpath(path) {
  return document.evaluate(path, document, null, XPathResult.FIRST_ORDERED_NODE_TYPE, null).singleNodeValue;
}
```

Why?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Problem: the code of outer functions isn't injected.**

Here's what executeScript does:

- it takes the function's code as plain text IIFE i.e. `(function foo() { ... })()`,
- it transfers the text to the web page,
- it selects the `ISOLATED` world environment where all content scripts of your extension run by default or the unsafe `MAIN` world where all page scripts run if you specified it explicitly,
- it executes that text as JavaScript code.

**Solution: put all necessary code and functions inside the function you inject.**

In your case getElementByXpath definition should be moved inside setPageBackgroundColor.

P.S. Naturally, the injected code can also use global variables/functions of previously injected content scripts via manifest.json's `content_scripts` (assuming their [run_at](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts#run_time) already occurred) or `executeScript`.